# converting mysql date and mysql time to VB DateTime

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime

I my MySQL database I have a date column and a time column. When using these values I have a lot of Problems with the right Format in VisualBasic. I know that there is plenty of possibilities but I just tried for 5 hours and did'nt find a method that worked for me.

This is the database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjGxy.jpg)

And here is the Vb.net Code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class ShowTermine
    Private Sub ShowTermine_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection("server=server.org;Port=3306; userid=userid; password=password; database=database")
    Try
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT * from bsp_termin WHERE userid =" & Form1.userID(Form1.Select1)
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim data As MySqlDataReader
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim mydate As Date


        conn.Open()
        command.CommandText = sqlquery
        command.Connection = conn
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        data = command.ExecuteReader

        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()

        While data.Read

            Me.TextBox1.Text += data(2).ToString("dd//MM//yyyy")
            Me.TextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine

            Me.TextBox2.Text += data(3).ToString
            Me.TextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine

            Me.TextBox3.Text += data(4).ToString
            Me.TextBox3.Text += Environment.NewLine

        End While
        data.Close()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Number & "    " & Err.Description)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I use ust the normal strings in TextBox1 the date is displayed as for example 2017-09-03. But I need the dd/mm/yyyy Format for this. So Me.TextBox1.Text += data(2).ToString("dd//MM//yyyy") gives an error. I also tried with CDate, but was not able to find the right Format for it.

How can I display the date Format in ListBox1 as "03.09.2017" and the time field in TextBox3 as "14:30" (hh/mm) ?

Comment: If the data type in the DB is Date, then get it back as a Date and use `ToString()` to display the format you want.  There is no need to convert anything - the MySQL DB provider provides the bridge from how it is stored to a NET `DateTime` type.   Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: "gives an error"  what was the error?

Comment: Also storing the date and time separately makes no sense unless they are the date for one thing and the time for another thing.  And your SQL should specify the columns you need in the order you want them, you code assumes the order (but doesnt seem to be even using the time column)

Comment: Ah ok...so it's better to use the DateTime - Type in the SQL database ?

Comment: The error when running Me.TextBox1.Text += data(2).ToString("dd//MM//yyyy") passage is "Conversion not valid from dd/MM/yyy to integer type.

Comment: Ok...I now it works. I used the DateTime Type in SQL and did then: Dim mydate As DateTime, Me.TextBox1.Text += mydate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), Me.TextBox3.Text += mydate.ToString("HH:mm"). Thank you Plutonix !

Comment: Tip: Add @Plutonix (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.